# Custom Functions using fetch method not working

Tags: office-js

We are trying to invoke api using fetch method as "POST" in Custom Functions but not able to get response and getting Network Failure issue.

We tried below things:
1) Tried to use fetch method and XMLHttpRequest method to invoke api in same functions.ts file.

Comment: Does it work on online ore Mac? It could be due to Full CORS support (not being yet enabled, but a workaround is coming soon)

Comment: We are trying only in  Excel Desktop but not checked on Mac. Kindly confirm.

Comment: Patel, For custom functions to bind api data into excel, when we try to use simple headers with api were able to get success response but when we are trying to use application/json type not able to get response in VS code. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Hi yes you are hitting due to the Full CORS support not being yet available on Windows, so your workaround of simple cors is correct.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-web-reqs

We will revert back when another workaround is available. Thanks

Comment: We tried in the following scenaios in Excel online and PFB findings.

1) We were able to get success response for GET request with header "application/json",

2) For the POST method api request with header "application/json" it is throwing below error .


message : "Network Request failed"
name    : "TypeError"
status 
code    : 204/No content Response

Kindly confirm.

Comment: Hi Patel, For the POST method api request with header "application.json" working fine in Office online. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Patel, Can you please provide tentative timeline in enabling full CORS so that it can be access from Excel desktop in windows.

Comment: Hi, good question. Team is working on enabling this now to get folks unblocked. For now I would see if you can use simple CORS or wrap your api around an endpoint that can handle it :)

Comment: Hi Patel, We have one more clarification that from Excel Task pane we were able to invoke the api POST method with header "application/json" using token and got the response successfully. But the same not working for custom functions which are invoked from Excel cells. Kindly provide the details how it is working on Excel task pane.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-runtime has details of the custom functions runtime on windows.

Answer (score 0):

I CONFIRMED THAT THIS SOLUTION WORKS!!

I found a workaround solution for a post request with json params hitting another origin within a custom function and without using the shared runtime!

Steps

1. Make fetch post on custom function. Only input your url and options with body: json. This will be treated as a simple cors request since there are no headers included. The url hits your taskpane url (“https://localhost:3000/api/getDataFromOtherOrigin” during development for example)
2. Add API proxy config to webpack dev server. So anything that anything with “/api” goes to my backend service from different origin.
3. Important step... add to proxy config to append any additional headers to make cors work. This is where you can add full cors headings to make request work.

Comment: Are you proposing this as a solution (or, at least, work around) to the OP’s problem? Or are you asking the community for input on your approach to solving a similar problem? If the former, I’d make that clear in your answer. If the latter, this should be posted as a new question. (I’m assuming the former, but didn’t want to edit your answer myself without confirming.)

Comment: I guess both. I’m having the same problems and am proposing this as a potential workaround. I’m asking the community if they think this would work.

Sorry, I’m trying to follow best practices with these question threads.